# Определить, какой radiobutton из нескольких выбран

Tags: asp.net

Существует множество radiobutton'ов (к примеру, 100 штук) на странице. И какой-то из них отмечен (checked, поставлена галочка). Как можно узнать более легким путем, какой именно отмечен.

Прошу помочь, сильно нужно!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) возьмите контрол который "оборачивает" (является контейнером) все эти радиобаттоны
2) у этого контрола-контейнера в свойстве Controls  ищите контролы типа RadioButton

Как вариант, во втором пункте рекурсивно прохоить по иерархии контролов и составлять список всех найденных RadioButton'ов.

Вот кусочек ... метод поиска котролов типа T... он рекурсивно вызывает себя и все найденные контролы запихает в коллекцию list

```
    private static void FindAllControls<T>(ControlCollection controls, IList<T> list) where T : Control
    {
        foreach (Control control in controls)
        {
            if (control is T)
            {
                list.Add((T) control);
            }
            if (control.HasControls())
            {
                FindAllControls(control.Controls, list);
            }
        }
    }
```

Но этот код вернет ВСЕ радиобаттоны, вам нужно будет из них выбирать те которые отмечены.