# Как достать SelectedValue из каждого комбобокса внутри ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

привет всем! У меня следующая проблема: есть такой код

```
<Window x:Class="Project.Sorts"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
Title="Window" Height="159.022" Width="527.82" ResizeMode="NoResize">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<ListView x:Name="lView" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsLW}" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="3">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="grView">
            <GridViewColumn Header="Col1" Width="Auto" x:Name="col1">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextForTb}" Margin="5,0,5,0"></TextBlock>
                        <ComboBox Width="Auto" MinWidth="80" ItemsSource="{Binding Cols}" SelectedIndex="0" >
                        </ComboBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Col2" Width="Auto" x:Name="col2">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Name="cbVars" Width="Auto" MinWidth="80" ItemsSource="{Binding Variants}"></ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button  Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Cancel" Margin="5,0,0,0" IsCancel="True"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnOK"  Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="ОК" Margin="5" Click="btnOK_Click"></Button>
</StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

получается вот такое окно:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIzBh.png
как можно достать SelectedValue из каждого комбобокса в данном ListView? Спасибо заранее за ответы!

Comment: Поищите на этом сайте решение, я уже где-то давал ответ на такой же вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

[нашел](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/188719/asp-net-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-radiobutton-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=188725#188725)

1. ищете все контролы-комбобоксы `FindAllControls<ComboBox>(this, list)`
2. и циклом вытягиваете свойство `SelectedValue`